# Powershell search within Directory recursively and replace list of words, then copy paste file in path

Tags: powershell, replace, find

Ia am clueless when it comes to powershell, I will eventually need to study this a bit, but for now I 
need some help please.
What I want to achieve.
I have a list of words

- **Find**:something   **ReplaceWith**:some_thing
- **Find**:lifeSpan    **ReplaceWith**:life_span
- **Find**:myWorld     **ReplaceWith**:my_world

I need to find and replace these list of words in XML files within a directory recursively.
For each file I need to find and replace these words and then move it to a folder.

Thanks in advance

Links to good starting point on learning Powershell welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Start with this and adapt it to your needs

```
$changeTable = @{
'something' = 'some_thing' 
'lifeSpan' = 'life_span' 
'myWorld' = 'my_world' 
}

$startDirectory = "c:\"

$fileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $startDirectory -Recurse -File
foreach ($file in $fileList)
{
    (Get-Content -Path $file.FullName) | ForEach-Object { 
        $currentLine = $_

        $changeTable.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
            $currentLine = $currentLine -replace $_.Key, $_.Value
        }

       $currentLine
    } | Set-Content -Path $file.FullName
}
```

The script first retrieve all files from the $startDirectory (recursively). Then it iterates the files and replaces the words from the change table above. To move the files to another location, take a look at the [Move-Item](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849852%28v=wps.620%29.aspx) cmdlet.